# Cake Shell showing code instead of options

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1

When i try to run the cake shell.. i receive a very weird message .. see below;

```
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.11
Content-type: text/html

################################################################################
#
# Bake is a shell script for running CakePHP bake script
# PHP 5
#
# CakePHP(tm) :  Rapid Development Framework (http://cakephp.org)
# Copyright 2005-2012, Cake Software Foundation, Inc.
#
# Licensed under The MIT License
# Redistributions of files must retain the above copyright notice.
#
# @copyright    Copyright 2005-2012, Cake Software Foundation, Inc.
# @link         http://cakephp.org CakePHP(tm) Project
# @package      app.Console
# @since        CakePHP(tm) v 2.0
# @license      MIT License (http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php)
#
################################################################################
LIB=$(cd -P -- "$(dirname -- "$0")" && pwd -P) && LIB=$LIB/$(basename -- "$0")

while [ -h "$LIB" ]; do
        DIR=$(dirname -- "$LIB")
        SYM=$(readlink "$LIB")
        LIB=$(cd "$DIR" && cd $(dirname -- "$SYM") && pwd)/$(basename -- "$SYM")
done

LIB=$(dirname -- "$LIB")/
APP=$(dirname $(cd $(dirname $0) && pwd))

exec php -q "$LIB"cake.php -working "$APP" "$@"

exit;
```

Any Idea's how to fix this problem?

I am using php 5.4.11, and i haven't made any changes to the code made by cakephp..

Thanks

Comment: you did not specify "how" you are invoking the shell. what is the exact command?

Comment: You are probably trying to run cake, but you can also run cake.php: `php Console/cake.php` from your app path

Comment: @mark, the command im try to run is $cake bake

@noslone, here is the output when i run the command `Status: 404 Not Found 
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.11
Content-type: text/html
No input file specified.`

there are a few reasons i would like to use the shell, 1 being for i18n, and the other being for the authentication and authorization.

Comment: UPDATE: as i was in the Consol directory thats why the 404 came... i think the shell is now working.. thanks @noslone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was calling the method from cake.. not cake.php

Thanks to @noslone!

To get the shell to load you should write the following command

```
$  php cake.php (Then the appropriate shell name)
```